# R Markdown remove last column

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm creating a **Five Number Summary** table with R Markdown but the last column is showing the Frequency.

My questions are:

1. Is there any way to remove that last column? and
2. Is there any way to transpose the table?

Please see the code below:

```
mpg %>%
  summarize( Min = min(cty),
             Q1 = quantile(cty, 0.25),
             Mean = mean(cty),
             Q3 = quantile(cty, 0.75),
             Max = max(cty)
  ) %>% table %>% knitr::kable(caption = "Five Number Summary")
```

Image of Five Number Summary table:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last column comes from `table`, you can remove that to drop the last column.

To transpose the data use `pivot_longer` from `tidyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
mpg %>%
  summarize( Min = min(cty),
             Q1 = quantile(cty, 0.25),
             Mean = mean(cty),
             Q3 = quantile(cty, 0.75),
             Max = max(cty)) %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
  knitr::kable(caption = "Five Number Summary")

Table: Five Number Summary

|name |    value|
|:----|--------:|
|Min  |  9.00000|
|Q1   | 14.00000|
|Mean | 16.85897|
|Q3   | 19.00000|
|Max  | 35.00000|
```